# Is it possible for DescribeInstances to return multiple instances when given instance ID filters?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-sdk

If I pass an instance ID as a filter to `DescribeInstances`, is it ever possible to get multiple reservations or instances? I am checking to see if I can simplify my code to just access index 0 of reservations or instances returned rather than a for loop

Comment: You can't have more than 1 instance sharing the instance id.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you will always receive zero or one instance when you are filtering by an instance ID.

Instance IDs are unique and you'll never receive a duplicate id. (More information: [Resource IDs Guide](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/resource-ids.html))

Even in cases where you have similar instance IDs for multiple instances, like `i-abc123` and `i-abc12345`, when you query the API it will retrieve you the information of the instance that has exactly the same id of your filter.